# How do I fix the window grid feature?

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz, window-management

I recently noticed that my Ubuntu 11.10 "window-grid" function is not working normally. It simply doesn't respond to my window drags to edges. I installed compizconfig-settings-manager and checked the settings on the *grid* option and it seems to be all set, although it's not working yet. How should I approach the problem?

Comment: What desktop session are you using? (Unity, Gnome Shell, ect.)

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention - unity.

Comment: The feature is "window grid" and not aero-snap :).

Comment: You see, it's not that easy to know a specific name for application whereas something showing similar attributes might be a helper for identification :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Unity, try you might want to try:

`compiz --replace & disown`

and then

`unity --reset`

in the terminal (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1755587).
If that doesn't solve it try looking at video drivers https://askubuntu.com/a/70440/38945.